# Java TLS 1.2 mutual authentication ends in timeout

Tags: java, ssl, timeout, tls1.2

I'm trying to connect through tls1.2 a client and a server. The client doesn't accept negotiating the cipher suite and don't know how to handle it.

I activate the ssl debug log, using the jvm arg javax.net.debug=SSL,handshake and was possible to see that the server receives the ClientHello. The server does the following:

```
Allow unsafe renegotiation: true
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads), READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 59
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: -1608433540 bytes = { BYTES }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA384withRSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA1withRSA
***
Warning: No renegotiation indication in ClientHello, allow legacy ClientHello
%% Initialized:  [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
matching alias: 1
Standard ciphersuite chosen: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
%% Negotiating:  [Session-1, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256]
*** ServerHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1517787192 bytes = { BYTES }
Session ID:  {BYTES}
Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Compression Method: 0
***
Cipher suite:  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
Version: V3
Subject: CN=subject_cn, O=subject_o, ST=PT, C=PT
Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
modulus: 29015987492349369229882970151237521665167957662510378450862540616622071854222726707712019298238587360512255793898937171225998663963095565298176277746307308842731113381493806617809755872635884654331768273583706812260841747492158530339516600730782510664549590782759663576346514054669279219650747333448381861327917816304051329475151462041391594291646947378495917447126780576974145276677671320013905217999988910738893500705389080299683007424691979475125418370308532635617504805014524719693897613122508271520133389717960149085839400280013902677341336202478008173403581601539568993773406783352636080748784965572598933438447
public exponent: 65537
Validity: [From: Fri Feb 02 19:20:34 WET 2018,
          To: Mon Jan 31 19:20:34 WET 2028]
Issuer: EMAILADDRESS=email@some.com, OU=some.com, O=subject_o, L=LOCATION, ST=PT, C=PT
SerialNumber: [    1007]

Certificate Extensions: 7
[1]: ObjectId: 2.16.840.1.113730.1.13 Criticality=false
Extension unknown: DER encoded OCTET string =
<OCTET STRING>


[2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
[EMAILADDRESS=email@some.com, OU=some.com, O=subject_o, L=LOCATION, ST=PT, C=PT]
SerialNumber: [    84adba39 85c4a2c4]
]

[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=false
BasicConstraints:[
CA:false
PathLen: undefined
]

[4]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
serverAuth
]

[5]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=false
KeyUsage [
DigitalSignature
Key_Encipherment
]

[6]: ObjectId: 2.16.840.1.113730.1.1 Criticality=false
NetscapeCertType [
SSL server
]

[7]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
<KEY IDENTIFIER>
]

]
Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
Signature:
<SIGNATURE>

]
chain [1] = [
[
Version: V1
Subject: EMAILADDRESS=email@some.com, OU=some.com, O=subject_o, L=LOCATION, ST=PT, C=PT
Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

Key:  Sun RSA public key, 4096 bits
modulus: 772642972303139838780709148958585369659263236466933975897684608521412098825919189354237122454024585440305346976195938447521179283381402256724407054886816122118702558876139603031503190893817256531731958885366418340075851175803932561840988978766750003938437503102425392846313350005528280678493861097867478907543592485376687739703952658746973265147862493215415696011008301372003730539214411254074488082192462310249699822199576712038207915612588146080682804726455410692837994635705721729847523735628418454502509894132524292922941334882301489573844052552145914371526175890068045278020298478426818036308867221570421452322486667351819099655095021674741234831795961314884813355920169539988863996321182070870364027323542460568464832570843818187525195851314441942294150743131343242106153746613659600974062131919507399729814610624864380422021048112964111616176710483770153874039347998021176496290178692983179619474804643147525920703982570793650375904590665612945490822575557619964743315412570783968475614249318137708703870150763126150252670464204907333319211805038483983840672999153429362303177433070797659970548018701110361935770595827178549690448631362303751647551358010951561847167019220036401389512936125354700325811813665747108156298237309
public exponent: 65537
Validity: [From: Fri Feb 02 11:41:04 WET 2018,
          To: Mon Jan 31 11:41:04 WET 2028]
Issuer: EMAILADDRESS=email@some.com, OU=some.com, O=subject_o, L=LOCATION, ST=PT, C=PT
SerialNumber: [    84adba39 85c4a2c4]

]
Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
Signature:
<SIGNATURE>

]
***
*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA, DSS, ECDSA
Supported Signature Algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA224withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
Cert Authorities:
<EMAILADDRESS=email@some.com, OU=some.com, O=subject_o, L=LOCATION, ST=PT, C=PT>
*** ServerHelloDone
Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads), WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 3079
Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads), READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 1334
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
Version: V3
Subject: CN=TEST01, O=subject_o, ST=PT, C=PT
Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
modulus: 23134801789439862758953434230286154428814279768287853373499436058114736605743710581551280904839901482179662922876777231282777161173622884062408603327815353852276746627442616624413051854717848004045100943694213226807191957763926809531243084935999278428818652492245444444875525639174280359137699705345587701327165516736271203211172284295019741808522601433815546974135394180726046632154867451842242323720019201204422829291922595592652513130397989212564095314679373054695806353606791437720734936324903589933612434115278813888829413855391631779541732018467103609097525698250908638923388363014150370482350492152108210301927
public exponent: 65537
Validity: [From: Mon Feb 05 09:04:16 WET 2018,
          To: Thu Feb 03 09:04:16 WET 2028]
Issuer: EMAILADDRESS=email@some.com, OU=some.com, O=subject_o, L=LOCATION, ST=PT, C=PT
SerialNumber: [    1014]

Certificate Extensions: 4
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
[EMAILADDRESS=email@some.com, OU=some.com, O=subject_o, L=LOCATION, ST=PT, C=PT]
SerialNumber: [    84adba39 85c4a2c4]
]

[2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=false
BasicConstraints:[
CA:false
PathLen: undefined
]

[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
serverAuth
clientAuth
]

[4]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
<key identifier>
]

]
Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
Signature:
<SIGNATURE>

]
***
Found trusted certificate:
[
[
Version: V1
Subject: EMAILADDRESS=email@some.com, OU=some.com, O=subject_o, L=LOCATION, ST=PT, C=PT
Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

Key:  Sun RSA public key, 4096 bits
modulus: 772642972303139838780709148958585369659263236466933975897684608521412098825919189354237122454024585440305346976195938447521179283381402256724407054886816122118702558876139603031503190893817256531731958885366418340075851175803932561840988978766750003938437503102425392846313350005528280678493861097867478907543592485376687739703952658746973265147862493215415696011008301372003730539214411254074488082192462310249699822199576712038207915612588146080682804726455410692837994635705721729847523735628418454502509894132524292922941334882301489573844052552145914371526175890068045278020298478426818036308867221570421452322486667351819099655095021674741234831795961314884813355920169539988863996321182070870364027323542460568464832570843818187525195851314441942294150743131343242106153746613659600974062131919507399729814610624864380422021048112964111616176710483770153874039347998021176496290178692983179619474804643147525920703982570793650375904590665612945490822575557619964743315412570783968475614249318137708703870150763126150252670464204907333319211805038483983840672999153429362303177433070797659970548018701110361935770595827178549690448631362303751647551358010951561847167019220036401389512936125354700325811813665747108156298237309
public exponent: 65537
Validity: [From: Fri Feb 02 11:41:04 WET 2018,
          To: Mon Jan 31 11:41:04 WET 2028]
Issuer: EMAILADDRESS=email@some.com, OU=some.com, O=subject_o, L=LOCATION, ST=PT, C=PT
SerialNumber: [    84adba39 85c4a2c4]

]
Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
Signature:
<SIGNATURE>

]
Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads), READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 262
*** ClientKeyExchange, RSA PreMasterSecret, TLSv1.2
SESSION KEYGEN:
PreMaster Secret:
<SECRET>
CONNECTION KEYGEN:
Client Nonce:
<CLIENT NONCE>
Server Nonce:
<SERVER NONCE>
Master Secret:
<MASTER SECRET>
Client MAC write Secret:
<CLIENT MAC SECRET>
Server MAC write Secret:
<SERVER MAC SECRET>
Client write key:
<CLIENT KEY>
Server write key:
<SERVER KEY>
... no IV derived for this protocol
***
found key for : 1
chain [0] = [
[
Version: V3
Subject: CN=subject_cn, O=subject_o, ST=PT, C=PT
Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
modulus: 29015987492349369229882970151237521665167957662510378450862540616622071854222726707712019298238587360512255793898937171225998663963095565298176277746307308842731113381493806617809755872635884654331768273583706812260841747492158530339516600730782510664549590782759663576346514054669279219650747333448381861327917816304051329475151462041391594291646947378495917447126780576974145276677671320013905217999988910738893500705389080299683007424691979475125418370308532635617504805014524719693897613122508271520133389717960149085839400280013902677341336202478008173403581601539568993773406783352636080748784965572598933438447
public exponent: 65537
Validity: [From: Fri Feb 02 19:20:34 WET 2018,
          To: Mon Jan 31 19:20:34 WET 2028]
Issuer: EMAILADDRESS=email@some.com, OU=some.com, O=subject_o, L=LOCATION, ST=PT, C=PT
SerialNumber: [    1007]

Certificate Extensions: 7
[1]: ObjectId: 2.16.840.1.113730.1.13 Criticality=false
Extension unknown: DER encoded OCTET string =
<OCTET STRING>


[2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
[EMAILADDRESS=email@some.com, OU=some.com, O=subject_o, L=LOCATION, ST=PT, C=PT]
SerialNumber: [    84adba39 85c4a2c4]
]

[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=false
BasicConstraints:[
CA:false
PathLen: undefined
]

[4]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
serverAuth
]

[5]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=false
KeyUsage [
DigitalSignature
Key_Encipherment
]

[6]: ObjectId: 2.16.840.1.113730.1.1 Criticality=false
NetscapeCertType [
SSL server
]

[7]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
<KEY IDENTIFIER>
]

]
Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
Signature:
<SIGNATURE>
]
chain [1] = [
[
Version: V1
Subject: EMAILADDRESS=email@some.com, OU=some.com, O=subject_o, L=LOCATION, ST=PT, C=PT
Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

Key:  Sun RSA public key, 4096 bits
modulus: 772642972303139838780709148958585369659263236466933975897684608521412098825919189354237122454024585440305346976195938447521179283381402256724407054886816122118702558876139603031503190893817256531731958885366418340075851175803932561840988978766750003938437503102425392846313350005528280678493861097867478907543592485376687739703952658746973265147862493215415696011008301372003730539214411254074488082192462310249699822199576712038207915612588146080682804726455410692837994635705721729847523735628418454502509894132524292922941334882301489573844052552145914371526175890068045278020298478426818036308867221570421452322486667351819099655095021674741234831795961314884813355920169539988863996321182070870364027323542460568464832570843818187525195851314441942294150743131343242106153746613659600974062131919507399729814610624864380422021048112964111616176710483770153874039347998021176496290178692983179619474804643147525920703982570793650375904590665612945490822575557619964743315412570783968475614249318137708703870150763126150252670464204907333319211805038483983840672999153429362303177433070797659970548018701110361935770595827178549690448631362303751647551358010951561847167019220036401389512936125354700325811813665747108156298237309
public exponent: 65537
Validity: [From: Fri Feb 02 11:41:04 WET 2018,
          To: Mon Jan 31 11:41:04 WET 2028]
Issuer: EMAILADDRESS=email@some.com, OU=some.com, O=subject_o, L=LOCATION, ST=PT, C=PT
SerialNumber: [    84adba39 85c4a2c4]

]
Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
Signature:
<SIGNATURE>
]
```

Eventually it gives a timeout and the ssl connection isn't finished.

I already tried to add the following properties to the jvm

- `sun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation=true`
- `sun.security.ssl.allowLegacyHelloMessages=true`

I think it lacks the "Finish" phase of SSL 2-WAY authentication

Can you help me understand what is wrong?

Comment: The client never negotiates the cipher suite, it just sends the list of the cipher suites it understands. From your debug log, we see it sends a list of only one cipher suite (TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256). The server, chooses among the client's list, the cipher it considers as the best (usually the most secure). If the server is authorized to use this only cipher sent by the client, it will use it. And again, your debug log shows it agrees with this one (TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256). So, what's the question ?

Comment: There is no renegotiation here. Whatever the problem is, it is NOT "the client doesn't know how to handle the renegotiation" because there is NO renegotiation. Is there nothing more in your trace? There should be at least two more messages from the server after ServerHello, then a response from the client or else an error.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thanks for your help, I updated the details. If you can help me I would appreciate.  Thanks

Comment: @EugèneAdell thanks for your help, I updated the details. If you can help me I would appreciate.  Thanks

Comment: You joined a server log, thanks. Do you also have the client's ? Or maybe do you have a network capture ? From what we see, the handshake is not going to its end, it hangs before the Client ChangeCipherSpec message which is never received. Can you also tell which java versions you are running ?

Comment: @EugèneAdell I found the problem. The server wasn't reading the handshake timeout and was rejecting the connection. I changed the server code (opensource project) and the timeout was fixed. Sorry for the silly mistake.

Comment: add an answer to your own question, explaining that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The server wasn't reading the handshake timeout property and using the default, the result was rejecting the connection. I changed the server code (opensource project) and the timeout was fixed.